# Postgres jsonb_array_elements

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with the next jsonb field -

```
{ "auth": [{"roles": ["role1", "role2"]}]}
```

When I do this query -

```
select jsonb_array_elements(role) as role from (
    select x -> 'roles' as role
    from test,
         jsonb_array_elements(data->'auth') x
```

the output format is

```
role
----
"role1"
"role2"
```

The current problem is that if I try to add where it doesn't work

`x.role = '"role1"'`, but this one does work `x.role like '%"role1"%'`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to restore "role" field as text data using ->> operator.

```
create table test (data jsonb);

insert into test values('{ "auth": [{"roles": ["role1", "role2"]}]}');

with cte as (
   select jsonb_array_elements(role) ->> 0 as role from 
     (
       select x -> 'roles' as role
              from test, jsonb_array_elements(data->'auth') x) y)
select role from cte where role = 'role1';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `jsonb_array_elements` returns the results as `jsonb`, and you get in trouble comparing that to a string literal.

Use `jsonb_array_elements_text` instead of the first `jsonb_array_elements` call, then the results will be of type `text`, which should give you no trouble.